# deep copy of the object through getters/setters

Tags: java, clone, cglib

I need to perform a deep copy of the object but only using getters/setter because sometimes I get CGLIB proxies instead of expected classes.

Solutions that I used:

- https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning - cool stuff that works even with classes that are not serializable but fails in case with CGIlib proxies
- Commons BeanUtils - only shallow copies as I understand

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Why not use reflection instead?

Comment: is it any good reason why you must clone your object?

Comment: @Adam, I'm trying to find some existing solutions, I'll use my own implementation in case if I won't find some solution

Comment: @user902383, yes, unfortunately, there's no workaround

Comment: _"... but fails in case with CGIlib proxies"_ How does it fail?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, proxy adds some other properties and wraps some fields of the instances changing their real class types e.g. java.util.Date could be changed to java.util.Date$CGLIB...$. Then it fails with ClassNoDefError